# How to delay playback of audio by 10 ms

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How would I delay the playback of the raw sound data by 30 ms in AS3? Is it as simple as storing the raw sound data and playing it back later?

Comment: Please give an example of your implementation, or proposed implementation. 'Raw sound data' could refer to regular sample playback, or streaming audio, or recorded audio. Are you using SoundChannel?

Comment: There's a slight pause (varies per system) when you start playing an audio or video file.  So you'll have to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution would be to place a sample-based pause before your audio data, with 10ms be equal to 441 pairs of samples. You will have to resample the PCM data for this to work correctly, though.